React useState variable is not updating after successful fetch request
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
const [videos, setVideos] = useState([]);
const [nextToken, setNextToken] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  getVideos();
}, []);

const getVideos = async () => {
  try {
    const url = nextToken
     ? API_URL+ "&token=" + nextToken
     : API_URL;
    console.log("Fetching data from:", url); // not appending API_URL 

  const data = await fetch(url);
  if (!data.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
  }

  const json = await data.json();
  setNextToken(json.nextPageToken);
  console.log(nextToken);
  setVideos((prevVideos) => [...prevVideos, ...json.items]);

} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
} finally {
  setIsLoading(false);
}

In above code nextToken is always null although getting successful response in json.nextPageToken. it is not appending with "API_URL+ "&token=" + nextToken"

Your code seems to have a few problems.

setToken(null) to initialise the token state, but then you're talking about nextToken, which hasn't been initialised. That's how you should initialise nextToken if it's meant to be like token.

Asynchronous Data and State Update: After running setVideos, you're changing the nextToken state. Although, because React updates states asynchronously, the new value of nextToken won't be available right away after calling setNextToken. You can now simply use the new json.nextPageToken in the URL construction instead.

Loading State-Based Conditional Rendering: In the end block, you're making isLoadingfalse. You are not setting it to true anywhere in the code, though. Setting it to true before getting data is important, and returning it to false after fetching is complete, whether it worked or not.


Here is the updated code:
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true); // Set initial loading state to true
const [videos, setVideos] = useState([]);
const [token, setToken] = useState(null);
const [nextToken, setNextToken] = useState(null); // Initialize nextToken state

useEffect(() => {
  getVideos();
}, []);

const getVideos = async () => {
  try {
    const url = nextToken
     ? API_URL + "&token=" + nextToken // Use updated nextToken here
     : API_URL;
    console.log("Fetching data from:", url);

    setIsLoading(true); // Set loading state to true before fetching data

    const data = await fetch(url);
    if (!data.ok) {
      throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
    }

    const json = await data.json();
    console.log("Response:", json);
    setNextToken(json.nextPageToken);
    console.log(nextToken);
    setVideos((prevVideos) => [...prevVideos, ...json.items]);

  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
  } finally {
    setIsLoading(false); // Set loading state back to false after fetching data
  }
}


updated my code with nextToken.  Once's we initialize value with setNextToken(json.nextPageToken) then on next api call url is not appended. it is always goes in else section.
